# Is "(unsigned)value" cast undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, casting

I am writing some code to test for a bit in a bit-field and I wrote this:

```cpp
return (unsigned)(m_category | category) > 0
```

I though this wouldn't compile, since I didn't give the integer type, but to my surprise it did. So I'm wondering, what does this do? Is it undefined?

Comment: This code doesn't compile on my machine.  Seems to be missing `int main() {` and a `;` at the end of the line, and a closing `}`.  Also `m_category` is undefined, and `category` is undefined.  I'm just as surprised as you are that it compiled.

Comment: If the compiler accepts something that it shouldn't accept, that's not undefined behaviour, that's a bug in the compiler (or a compiler extension).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unsigned` is the same as `unsigned int`.

The cast will convert the signed integer to unsigned as follows:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions

> ```
> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the smallest
> unsigned value equal to the source value modulo 2n
> where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type. 
>
> That is, depending on whether the destination type is wider or narrower,
> signed integers are sign-extended[footnote 1] or truncated
> and unsigned integers are zero-extended or truncated respectively.
> ```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat love how cppreference states that all platforms with C++ use two's complement while department next to mine works on one with one's complement platform for ages :P

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie :o What's that platform?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat there are multiple, while I can't say what they use (even if I knew),  there is still Unisys\Dorado and their analogs. In general it's a telemetry\avionics\RSP\software-defined radio thing, because precise DACs and many sensor designs use one's complement  for simplicity and same-time response.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie never heard of that one before, had to search it up :|

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I realized they were talking about the mathematical sense which is Why I deleted the comment. The standard has this nice wording for the same: **Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.** So I stand corrected, signed -> unsigned was always defined since they use the mathematical modulo.

Comment: s/The standard/The C standard/ in the last comment.